# Find list items and convert its ID to lowercase, add hyphens

Tags: javascript, jquery, find

I have multiple unordered lists (an accordion to be exact) on the same page. Each list item has a unique id that basically is user generated characters (thus could be anything). I'm trying to convert each unique ID to lowercase and replace any spaces to hyphens.

The code I'm playing with sits within a `.each` function as there are multiple accordions on the same page and its still outputting the user generated ID and not the converted ID:

```
$('ul.responsive-accordion').each(function() {

   var question = $('ul.responsive-accordion').find('li');
   var questionhash = $(question).attr('id');

   convertedhash = questionhash.toLowerCase().replace(/ /g, '-');

});
```

When I output to console using the below its only outputting the first items ID twice and not the other items (in this example there should 3 more list item ID's being shown):

```
// Replace spaces with hyphens
var question = $('ul.responsive-accordion').find('li');
var questionhash = $(question).attr('id');

console.log ( questionhash );

convertedhash = questionhash.toLowerCase().replace(/ /g, '-');

console.log ( convertedhash );
```

See output:

[image]

Comment: That could bring invalid HTML, getting duplicate IDs if user enters more than once same input data. It could be an issue or not... Anyway, purpose of `id` attribute isn't to bring data, use `data-*` attribute or dataset object instead. Question is: why do you need to set `id`? Do you want to send data to server later?

Comment: Its to generate a hash so I can link directly to an accordion item via URL

Comment: Then it makes sense to use IDs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to loop them all, by using [`each()`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/)

```
$('ul.responsive-accordion li').each( function() {
    var id = $(this).attr('id');
    console.log( id );
    var newId = id.toLowerCase().replace(/ /g, '-');
    console.log( newId );
    $(this).attr('id', newId);
});
```

Comment: This seems to do it, however I cannot seem to replace the contents of the user generated id with the converted newId. For some reason $(id).replaceWith(newId); doesn't work, any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

You are not utilizing the each function properly

```
$('ul.responsive-accordion').each(function() {
   // use this to get access to the item in the loop
   var question = $(this).find('li');
   var questionhash = $(question).attr('id');

   convertedhash = questionhash.toLowerCase().replace(/ /g, '-');

});
```

Alternatively, you could also do:

```
$('ul.responsive-accordion').each(function(idx, elem) {

   var question = $(elem).find('li');
   var questionhash = $(question).attr('id');

   convertedhash = questionhash.toLowerCase().replace(/ /g, '-');

});
```

Answer (score -2):

You want to initialize a variable outside of loop.

```
 var question = $('ul.responsive-accordion').find('li');

$(question).each(function() {

   var questionhash = $(question).attr('id');

   convertedhash = questionhash.toLowerCase().replace(/ /g, '-');

});
```